# React Navigation accessing redux state

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

I'm wondering if there is a way to access redux states in App.js?

[image: App.js code screenshot]

Comment: I'm planning to set a bottom navigation icon wherein the image is coming from the redux state

Comment: When asking a question, don't put screenshots. To debug, we copy-paste code and that becomes impossible if you take screenshots. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please edit the question and copy-paste the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to obtain redux data from within App.js. You can do this by using the `store#getState` method. The only problem by using this method is that App.js will **not** be updated whenever the redux store changes.

To obtain data from the redux state and also subscribe to changes automatically you will have to use the `useSelector` hook or wrap your component with a HOC.

Currently, you're initializing the `bottomTabNavigator` outside a React component. I suggest that you move this to a dedicated container named `MainFlow`. This container will be responsible for rendering the `bottomTabNavigator`. Load this container for the mainFlow route instead of the createBottomTabNavigator.

```
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { useSelector } from 'redux';

// import your page containers

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default function MainFlow() {
  // here you can use the `useSelector` hook to get the icon
  const tabBarIcon = useSelector(state => state.routing.tabBarIcon);

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator
        screenOptions={() => ({
          tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => {
            // render icon
          }
        })}
      >
        <Tab.Screen name="homeScreen" component={HomePageContainer} />
        <Tab.Screen name="explore" component={ExplorePageContainer} />
        {/* rest of the tabs */}
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this Christiaan, I'm currently using React Navigation 4.0.10, is it still possible to transfer the initialization of bottomTabNavigator to a dedicated container?

Comment: Yes, that would still be possible according to the documentation: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/bottom-tab-navigator